# Values not set when I post my form to server

Tags: angular

I use angular 8 in my project.

Here is my form:

```
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <h2 class="text-center">New fridge</h2>
        <div class="card mt-3">
            <div class="card-body">
              <form [formGroup]="newFridgeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4">Fridge name </label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name"/>

                  <label class="col-md-4">Product type </label>
                  <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="description"/> -->
                  <select class="custom-select" formControlName="fridgeTypeId">
                    <option value="">Choose type</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let pt of fridgeTypes" [ngValue]="pt.id">{{pt.text}}</option>
                 </select>  
                 <label class="col-md-4">Date Creation </label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="date" value="{{dateVal | date: 'M/dd/yyyy'}}" readonly/>  
                 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" formControlName="uid" value="{{this.authenticationService.currentUserValue.id}}"/> 
                 </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4" [disabled]="newFridgeForm.invalid">
                        <span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                      Add
                    </button>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/fridgeList']">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4 ml-1">Back</button>
                  </a>
                 </div>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here how it looks:

[image]

As you can see I have id form that is hidden and date that display current date and it's not editable .

And here is form group in TypeScript:

```
this.newFridgeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  fridgeTypeId: ['', Validators.required]
  uid: [''],
  date: ['']
});
```

}

And here is how I sent form group values to server after Add butten is hitted:

```
this.fridgeService.save(this.newFridgeForm.value)
.subscribe(
  data => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.alertService.success('Add new product', true);
      this.router.navigate(['/productList']);        
  },
  error => {
      this.alertService.error(error);
      this.loading = false;
  });
```

When I check in console window it looks like this:

[image]

while I expect that that all fields will have value including date and uid.

Why date and uid is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `value` from your HTML and set those values in your form like this and I am sure it will work.

`<input type="hidden" class="form-control" formControlName="uid"/>`

```
this.newFridgeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  fridgeTypeId: ['', Validators.required],
  uid: [this.authenticationService.currentUserValue.id],
  date: [dateVal]
});
```

`formControlName="uid"` will automatically bind the current user id

Comment: thanks for post.and how can I use pipe if I remove value or how can I decorate date?

Comment: You have to use Date Pipe in your component.ts file, Like this

`constructor(private _datePipe: DatePipe){
 this.dateVal = _datePipe.transform(Date.now(),'yyyy-MM-dd');
}`

Comment: what is DatePipe ?from where I import it?or should I cretae it by my self?

Comment: It depends if you want custom date format then create your own. Otherwise you can use angular built in date pipe which can be imported like this.
`import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';`

For detail explanation you can also read the documentation of Date Pipe. 
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Hi @Michael does this answer fixed your issue?

Comment: Hi. no I have this error after I add code above: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FridgeAddComponent -> DatePipe]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FridgeAddComponent -> DatePipe]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for DatePipe!

Comment: Yes you have to add DatePipe service in your `app.module.ts`.

`providers: [DatePipe]`

Comment: I add to app.module.ts providers and now I get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined
    at new FridgeAddComponent (fridge-add.component.ts:36)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203755/discussion-between-ali-memon-and-michael).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203767/discussion-between-ali-wahab-and-michael).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to use `value` attribute in your HTML elements as it doesn't have two-way binding. Either use `[(ngModel)]`or if you are dealing with forms, use `formControlName`.
In some cases you are using both `formControlName` and `value`. For example in `uid` input, you should remove `value` attribute, and in your component set the `uid` control accordingly:

```
this.newFridgeForm.controls.uid.setValue(this.authenticationService.currentUserValue.id);
```